# Load file from resources

Tags: micronaut

I want load text file in runtime which I have in resources file. I see that file after compile is in build directory (build/resources/main/locker_locations.csv). But I can't resolve path which access to this file. I tried ResourceLoader, but it can't inject. I process it in method `@EventListener public void loadGeolocation(ServerStartupEvent event){}` which should runs after startup.

Comment: Its a bug that was fixed that `ResourceResolver` can't be injected. You can inject `Environment` in the meantime and use that since it implements that contract

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got solution from [Micronaut Gitter](https://gitter.im/micronautfw/). It neccessary to use `ResourceResolver#getResource(“classpath:locker_locations.csv”)`

Comment: Hi Andrew, can you share how you inject the ResourceLoader?